# How to use input redirection with a special integer as divider and until eof

Tags: c++, input, linked-list

I need to use input redirection to store integers into two separate linked lists.  The sets of integers are seperated by a special integer 99999.  I need help to read until the end of file and ignore 99999.  Also becuase there is no 99999 at the end of input I cant stop it using that.

Sample of Input
9 1 7 8 3
99999
6 5 4 3 11 -2

If I was using fstream I feel like I could just use eof function.  However when trying to do this by redirection it never seems to end.

```
LinkedList L1, L2; //Two linked lists
    int x;


        while(1)
        {
            cin>>x;
            L1.insertNode(x);//Function to add to linked list
            if(x==99999) break; //Attempt at ignoring 99999
        }
        while(1)
        {
            cin>>x;
            L2.insertNode(x);
            if(x=='\n') break; // Attempt to stop at eof
        }
```

Comment: '\n' is a line break. Since `x` is of type integer you store the ASCII value of '\n' in `x`, which is likely to be 10 on your computer. The design does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the fact that `ifstream::operator bool ()` returns `false` at EOF to terminate your loops.

Code (modified to use `std::list`):

```
std::list <int> L1, L2;
int x;

while(std::cin >> x)
{
    L1.push_back(x);//Function to add to linked list
    if (x==99999) break; //Attempt at ignoring 99999
} 

while(std::cin >> x)
    L2.push_back(x);
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/xU48I3DlNFqvS9OF)

Comment: TY TY!!! I just had to put the break before L1.push_back(x) to prevent it from being added to the list :)

Comment: Yes, I thought that might be what you wanted.